# Получить рандомное double число на заданном промежутке

Tags: c, случайные-числа

Нужно сгенерировать псевдослучайные дробные числа на промежутке (-1;0)∪(0;1).

Погуглил, подумал, выяснил, как генерить их на промежутке (0;1):

```
double Random(void)
{
    double num = (double)rand() / ((double)rand() + 0.1);
    return num - floor(ret);
}



int main()
    {
       srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
       k = Random();
       return 0;
    }
```

Получаются вот такие приемлемые для моей подзадачи числа:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот как генерировать числа в вышеуказанном промежутке, я никак не могу придумать...

Comment: То, что получаемые таким образом числа будут распределены неравномерно (грубо говоря, вероятность получить 0,5 будет выше, чем вероятность получить 0,01) — этого требует Ваша задача?

Comment: Задача у меня остается той же самой, что была озвучена - нужно получить действительные случайные числа на промежутке (-1;0)∪(0;1). На самом деле, насколько я понимаю, для моей подзадачи(инициализация синаптических весов нейронной сети) высокая степень случайности не очень важна, хотя и желательна. Важен именно заданный промежуток.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы, буду разбираться.

Comment: Вот тут хорошее описание, но для C++: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504652/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0/504653#504653

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простейший самопальный вариант, который работает почти со всеми компиляторами, кроме, почему-то, Intel C 15. Основан на формате IEEE-754. Мы генерируем знаменатель D, как денормализованное число, мантисса которого равна 2<sup>32</sup>. Генерируется числитель r, который тоже денормализован и меньше 2<sup>32</sup> (при этом не равен нулю). Затем делим r на D, гарантированно получая число между 0 и 1. Затем в зависимости от знака s делаем его либо положительным, либо отрицательным. Вместо генерации s как у меня можно (и даже лучше) использовать какой-нибудь другой генератор чисел из диапазона от 0 до 2<sup>32</sup>-1 (только НЕ rand(), потому что у него другой диапазон), потому что этот линейный генератор не очень стойкий, чередует чётность чисел и повторяется через полный цикл.

К сожалению, код машинно-зависим, он зависит от порядка байт в слове и от формата IEEE-754, поэтому подходит только для кустарной работы, но не для серьёзных проектов.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double r;
unsigned int s = 17;

static double get_random ( ) {
  double D = 0.0;
  do s = 19993*s+1; while (s==0); // s != 0  
  *((unsigned int*)&D+1) = 1; // D = 0x0000000100000000
  r = 0.0;
  *(unsigned int *)&r = s;    // r = 0x00000000[   s  ]
  r /= D;                     // r < 1.0
  if (s&1) r = -r;
  return r;
}

int main() {  
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i<100; i++)
    printf ("%lf\n", get_random());
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Интересное решение.. Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле у вас какой-то странноватый генератор. Он будет явно не равномерно распределён.

Если вам не нужна большая энтропия то можно использовать

```
    int t = rand()%65536;
    t-= 32768;
    if (t>=0) t++;
    return t/32768.0;
```

Если нужно то rand() сам по себе плохая идея особенно на Win платформе.

Comment: Благодарю! Не могли бы вы пояснить/скинуть ссылку, где можно разобраться с тем, какие генераторы хуже, какие лучше, и хотя бы в общем, почему мой вариант плох?

Comment: Попробовал Ваш пример, на винде за 20 прогонов с выборкой по 8 значений не сгенерировалось ни одного положительного числа..

Comment: https://ideone.com/Qj7mXU странно, в пределах погрешности.

Comment: @kekyc Ваш вариант не скажу что плох, но на первый взгляд кажется что он слишком сложный всё же 2 случайных числа генерировать, и вот простой вариант https://ideone.com/U5MSOS на нём видно что значения ближе к 0 возникают чаще чем к 1. На самом деле всё это нужно проверять специальными тестами, но общая картина в целом и по таким видна.

Comment: Остановился на [этом](http://www.rgba.org/articles/sfrand/sfrand.htm) варианте. Судя по выборке выдает очень даже хорошие для меня результаты. 

Вообще, творились странные вещи - ваш код и правда выдавал приемлемые результаты на сайте, но у меня на машине выдавал только отрицательные значения. Я свой код перекопал, но ничего мешающего правильной работе не нашел.

В любом случае, спасибо за ответы; теперь хоть чуток поумнел:)

Answer (score 2):

Не обязательно же придумывать, можно просто погуглить:

[How can I get random integers in a certain range?](http://c-faq.com/lib/randrange.html)

> The obvious way,
>
> `rand() % N     /* POOR */`
>
> (which tries to return numbers from 0 to N-1) is poor, because the low-order bits of many random number generators are distressingly non-random. (See question 13.18.) A better method is something like
>
> `(int)((double)rand() / ((double)RAND_MAX + 1) * N)`
>
> ...
>
> For any of these techniques, it's straightforward to shift the range, if necessary; numbers in the range [M, N] could be generated with something like
>
> `M + rand() / (RAND_MAX / (N - M + 1) + 1)`

И ещё много советов в англоязычной версии SO:

[How to generate a random number from within a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509679/how-to-generate-a-random-number-from-within-a-range)

```
unsigned int rand_interval(unsigned int min, unsigned int max)
{
    int r;
    const unsigned int range = 1 + max - min;
    const unsigned int buckets = RAND_MAX / range;
    const unsigned int limit = buckets * range;

    /* Create equal size buckets all in a row, then fire randomly towards
     * the buckets until you land in one of them. All buckets are equally
     * likely. If you land off the end of the line of buckets, try again. */
    do
    {
        r = rand();
    } while (r >= limit);

    return min + (r / buckets);
}
```