# Вывод рандомного слова на экран Qt

Tags: android, c++, qt

Не могу реализовать вывод одного слова на экран,слов будет очень много и нужно их где-то хранить и из этого хранилища по нажатию кнопки выводить одно рандомное слово.Помогите,пожалуйста.

Comment: предлагаю запихать в таблицу sqlite.Оттуда брать кол-во записей в таблице и генератором брать по уникальному номеру или по порядку

Comment: Очень много - это сколько? В принципе, словарный запас любого языка легко помещается в память любого современного смартфона.

Comment: Не так много,думаю, 1500 слов-максимум.

Answer (score 3):

Хранить в sqlite, и с помощью функции rand выбирать случайное число в пределах общего количества слов. И выводить по порядковому номеру или как Вам удобнее.

```
rand() % 10 + 1; //От 1 до 10
```

**Update:**

Посмотрите [вот](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) и [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504652/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0/505159#505159)

Comment: Пробовал использовать rand,но он выдает рандомное число единажды,после первого числа,сколько бы я не запускал программу будет тоже число.Пробовал сделать srand с зависимостью от времени,но там не совсем рандомное число выдает

Comment: @Tokiwartoot сразу после запуска программы сделайте ``srand(time(0));`` тогда при каждой запуске будут разные случайные числа.

Comment: Если уж приводите нормальную ссылку, то и код приведите из неё(я про первую). `rand` не рекомендуется к использованию, т.к. является чрезвычайно плохим генератором.

Comment: Там есть пример, зачем дублировать